# Get Google Cast queue items with the Chrome Sender API

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

In the Google Cast Chrome Sender API, there are several methods on [`Media`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Media) for manipulating the queue, such as as [`queueAppendItem`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Media.html#queueAppendItem). However, there does not appear to be a way to get what is currently in the queue. There is [`Media.items`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Media#items), but it contains only the next three queue items, not the entire queue. The documentation does not mention that, but it is what I observed in practice.

The [Queueing topic in the Android Sender API documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/queueing) mentions that the Android version does not keep the entire queue in memory because the queue might be large. That makes sense, and I could see why the Chrome Sender API would only track the next 3 queue items. But at least the Android version exposes `getItemIds` and `getItemAtIndex`. I have not found an equivalent of those in the Chrome Sender API.

I found [an unanswered question about receiving a callback on queue change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53902121/135889), but even getters to inspect the queue would be fine for me.

How can I reconstruct the full queue with the Chrome Sender API?

Comment: Maybe you can use Media.currentItemId(). What's the scenario here for manipulating the queue?

Comment: I am building a music player application and I want to display the queue.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, as far as I am aware this is still impossible as of February 2021. I haven’t looked into it lately, but from a quick glance, it looks like nothing changed since then.